# How can I style something differently in iOS when in a web app opened from the home screen?

Tags: ios, css, media-queries, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to style my PWA differently when it is opened from the iOS home screen. I have this in my `<head>`:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

I thought I could use a media query inside a `@supports` query like this:

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  // default ios styles

  @media (display-mode: fullscreen) {
    // ios full screen styles (web app opened from home screen) 
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I'm using an iPhone 6s with iOS 13.1.3. Is there a different approach I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

Using `standalone` instead of `fullscreen` works.

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  // default ios styles

  @media (display-mode: standalone) {
    // ios web app styles (opened from home screen)
  }
}
```